# PayPal IPN page not being hit even though purchase goes through

Tags: php, paypal, live, paypal-ipn

I tested everything fine in the Sandbox, the IPN listener would work as expected and I would the expected responses in my mail as well.

I've gone live now but although the customer can place a purchase fine, and PayPal even gives a purchase transaction ID, it appears that the IPN listener has stopped working, it never hears the IPN from PayPal, and so none of the business logic processing that's supposed to happen fires whenever a purchase is made. What's wrong?

There's nothing wrong with my IPN listener code, because it worked perfectly in the sandbox environment. I used this IPN code: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

It's just not getting hit at all. This is how I use the NVP request:

```
$return_url = urlencode("http://www.zeej.com.sa/printshop/checkout4_confirm.php");
$cancel_url = urlencode("http://www.zeej.com.sa/printshop/cancel.php");
$notify_url = urlencode("http://www.zeej.com.sa/printshop/ipn.php");
$nvpStr ="&BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=".$usd_total."&L_BUTTONVAR2=return=".$return_url."&L_BUTTONVAR3=cancel_return=".$cancel_url."&L_BUTTONVAR4=no_shipping=1&L_BUTTONVAR5=notify_url=".$notify_url."&L_BUTTONVAR6=custom=".$custom_qs;

$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('BMCreateButton', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    $hostedbuttonid = $httpParsedResponseAr["HOSTEDBUTTONID"];
} else  {
    die('Please refresh the page and try again. <br />Error: Create Payment Button Failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
```

And this is my PPHttpPost code, which I also got from somewhere online and was working perfectly well during sandbox testing:

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;
    $environment = "";

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.


    $API_UserName = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 
    $API_Password = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 

    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp"; // 
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp"; 
    }
    $version = urlencode('98.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature".$nvpStr_;

    //echo($nvpreq);

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your IPN history within your PayPal account to verify that it is actually getting sent out from PayPal.  Also, if you view the IPN message within your history it should give you a status code that is being returned if one is being returned.

Comment: I just checked the IPN history, and the transaction actually is there! And its status is "sent". I also went to developer.paypal.com and used the IPN simulator, but again my program couldn't hear the IPN hit. Where is the problem? While running in the sandbox environment I had no issues. Is this a bad URL? "http://www.zeej.com.sa/printshop/ipn.php"... should it not have such a long path or something?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the issue. It wasn't any problem with paypal.
I went to my IPN page `www.mydomain.com/printshop/ipn.php` and PHP showed me I had a syntax error on the page... 
so that's why it wasn't accepting any IPN hits, because it wasn't even running! Fixed the syntax error and now I'm receiving IPN hits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your servers access logs, and error logs to make sure the script is not erroring out? There are some IPN issues that are going on right now which may be causing yoru issue that you are seeing.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with [PayPal's Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts), so that this issue can be looked into.  This way you will also be notified once the issue has been resolved.